# Delete non-existant pages from MediaWiki that are listed in Special:allPages

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm trying to delete two pages:

- http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Uk:%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0
- http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Uk:%C3%83%C3%AE%C3%AB%C3%AE%C3%A2%C3%AD%C3%A0_%C3%B1%C3%B2%C3%AE%C3%B0%C2%B3%C3%AD%C3%AA%C3%A0

These two pages are in the Special:AllPages list even though they return 404 not found status.

How can I delete them?

Comment: I'm confused about your question, but you should review the code that dynamically generates these pages. If it seems to be working fine otherwise, and there were no modifications to the static code recently, then I would scan my box for malware with consideration to the format just to be safe. The pages shouldn't be on the physical box itself if it's returned a 404 error. I'm not sure, but I want to say that the pages output looks like a hashed url encoded string.

Comment: Though they're hashed URLs, they forward to the proper page names at: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Uk:Ãîëîâíà_ñòîð³íêà and http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Uk:Головна_сторінка

The notice says "Bad title: The requested page title was invalid, empty, or an incorrectly linked inter-language or inter-wiki title. It may contain one or more characters that cannot be used in titles."
How can I delete a page that shows this error?
The two pages are listed on http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Special:AllPages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first page [has never been deleted](https://wiki.lxde.org/uk/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%96%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8&page=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), the second has never been created and [is not in Special:AllPages](https://wiki.lxde.org/uk/Special:AllPages).

That said, it can sometimes happen that the database contains stale links which never get refreshed despite [purges](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge) and a functioning [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue); in such a case it may be necessary to run [refreshLinks.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RefreshLinks.php), specifically:

```
php maintenance/refreshLinks.php --dfn-only
```